# Mac OS X Server 10.6.6 "disables" CPU in VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, vmware-fusion

I installed Mac OS X Server 10.6.0 in VMWare Fusion the other night and it worked perfectly, until I ran Software Update. I upgraded to 10.6.6 through the combo updater, and now when I start the VM it says:

> "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. You will need to power off or reset the virtual machine at this point."

I've switched the operating system in the options to OS X Server 32bit, 64bit, and even to Windows 7, and nothing has worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this vm running on mac hardware?

Comment: Yep. VMware Fusion 3.1.2 on a MBP early 2011.

Comment: @wjlafrance, VMWare is a company with over 40 different products, don't just use their name in future questions, use the product name. It's also not really a serverfault type question so I'm moving it to our sister site superuser.com.

Comment: What does vmware support say about this?

Comment: Did you try powering off or resetting the virtual machine? I think it is indicating that it won't restore a VM that is suspended. A hard power off may work.

Comment: You can run OS X VMs on apple machines. It is not a hackintosh question.

Comment: This message means the software running inside the VM has issued the _CLI_ and _HLT_ instructions. It usually happens when the OS crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1 CPU assigned to the VM instance try setting the number of CPU's to 1.

Other than that, make sure you have USB 2.0 support enabled.  Sounds wierd, but it can cause this exact problem (ref: [VMWare Fusion Rel. Notes](http://www.vmware.com/support/fusion2/doc/releasenotes_fusion_204.html)

Comment: Hm, thanks for the attempt but I set it to "Mac OS X Server 10.6" as well as it's 64-bit counterpart, 1 processor, USB2.0. Same issue. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling vmware fusion. It could have had a library issue which isn't uncommon on a Mac. Also running a permission repair after an upgrade can help clear up issues like this when a resource file can become incorrectly permissioned.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice. Did a permissions check, no fix. Reinstalled VMware, no fix. :(

Answer (score -1):

This isn't what you're looking for, but you *should* be able to use the image under VirtualBox 4.0 - it can read VMware's .VMDK files, and it can run OS X Server.  I'm currently using 10.6.6 under VBox. (it's slower than VMWare for some stuff, though - be warned)